# Надо написать код, который суммирует заранее три заданных числа, но если есть число меньше нуля, то код его игнорирует. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

```
a, b, c, = int(input()), int(input()), int(input())
if a and b and c < 0:
   a, b, c = 0
else:
    print(a + b + c)
```

Почему мой код не работает?
Объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: Он совсем не отражает задачу. `if` неверный в любом случае, он всегда выполнится. Но надо три отдельных `if` делать, если совсем просто хочется.

Answer (score 0):

```
if a and b and c < 0:
```

Для интерпретатора означает:
Если a True и b True и c < 0, то ...

А у вас всё же другая цель, проверить что они больше нуля.
Подсказка:
Вот это `int(input()), int(input()), int(input())` вернёт кортеж.
Можно посчитать сумму элементов кортежа, больших 0, пробежавшись по нему, и отсеяв лишнее.

Решение:

```
to_sum = int(input()), int(input()), int(input())
result_sum = sum(el for el in to_sum if el > 0)
print(result_sum)
```

Comment: Можете объяснить подробнее, пожалуйста?

Comment: @NewSmartCoder Добавил решение.

Answer (score 0):

вариант 1:

```
res = sum(i for i in (a, b, c) if i >= 0)
```

вариант 2:

```
res = sum(filter(lambda i: i >= 0, (a, b, c)))
```

вариант 3:

```
res = sum(i if i >= 0 else 0 for i in (a, b, c))
```

вариант 4:

```
res = sum((0, i)[i >= 0] for i in (a, b, c))
```

вариант 5:

```
res = sum(map(lambda i: (0, i)[i >= 0], (a, b, c)))
```

вариант 6:

```
res = sum(map(lambda i: i if i >= 0 else 0, (a, b, c)))
```

вариант 7:

```
res = sum(len('*' * i) for i in (a, b, c))
```

вариант 8:

```
res = 0

for i in (a, b, c):
    if i >= 0:
        res += i
```

вариант 9:

```
from functools import reduce

res = reduce(lambda i, j: (j + i) if j >= 0 else i, (a, b, c))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a, b, c, = int(input()), int(input()), int(input())
if a < 0 or b < 0 or c < 0:
   a, b, c = 0, 0, 0
else:
    print(a + b + c)
```